# Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Getting below error while trying to import one graphml file in Neo4j 3.5.0.

**Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed**: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.import.graphml`: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot open file drwho.graphml for reading.

The graphml file is at the following location=> `.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-8751e5e4-05fd-4032-b3d8-abbd2bb883e8\installation-3.5.0`.

I have added the below line in settings.

```
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

After adding the above line, I am trying to execute the below code snippet in Neo4j browser and getting exception `Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed`

```
CALL apoc.import.graphml('drwho.graphml', {batchSize: 10000, storeNodeIds: false, readLabels: true})
```

It should upload the graphml file to Neo4j. I have searched over net multiple times but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today. In case you haven't found a fix yet, I simply copied the file to the root of my users directory and changed the file location to match.